# dplyr output incorrectly calculating yearly mean

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

Here's the dput() of my data:

```
data <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(8586, 8614, 8642, 8670, 8698, 
8726, 8754, 8789, 8817, 8845, 8873, 8901, 8915, 8951, 8978, 9006, 
9034, 9062, 9091, 9153, 9181, 9209, 9244, 9272, 9304, 9342, 9370, 
9399, 9426, 9459, 9497, 9524, 9559, 9587, 9622, 9678, 9706, 9734, 
9762, 9797, 9825, 9860, 9888, 9903, 9946, 9982, 10010, 10043, 
10050, 10095, 10133, 10161, 10178, 10224, 10252, 10280, 10308, 
10339, 10417, 10441, 10456, 10469, 10480, 10483, 10497, 10511, 
10525, 10553, 10567, 10596, 10609, 10623, 10641, 10651, 10665, 
10693, 10707, 10721, 10742, 10756, 10767, 10802, 10816, 10830, 
10844, 10858, 10879, 10893, 10907, 10970, 10984, 10998, 11012, 
11026, 11040, 11054, 11145, 11149, 11159, 11173, 11187, 11201, 
11215, 11229, 11242, 11257, 11271, 11292, 11313, 11341, 11369, 
11375, 11383, 11397, 11411, 11435, 11453, 11467, 11478, 11480, 
11495, 11508, 11509, 11536, 11552, 11580, 11636, 11664, 11734, 
11762, 11797, 11809, 11853, 11867, 11895, 11908, 11923, 11937, 
11951, 11964, 11979, 11993, 12007, 12021, 12035, 12063, 12077, 
12091, 12105, 12119, 12133, 12147, 12160, 12175, 12189, 12231, 
12245, 12259, 12273, 12301, 12315, 12329, 12343, 12357, 12371, 
12385, 12399, 12427, 12441, 12455, 12469, 12483, 12497, 12511, 
12524, 12535, 12553, 12574, 12592, 12630, 12644, 12658, 12672, 
12686, 12700, 12714, 12728, 12742, 12756, 12770, 12791, 12805, 
12819, 12833, 12847, 12861, 12875, 12888, 12903, 12917, 12938, 
12973, 12987, 13001, 13015, 13029, 13043, 13056, 13071, 13085, 
13099, 13116, 13126, 13138, 13155, 13168, 13169, 13179, 13190, 
13201, 13218, 13232, 13248, 13259, 13274, 13287, 13301, 13323, 
13343, 13358, 13372, 13386, 13400, 13413, 13428, 13442, 13456, 
13470, 13484, 13488, 13497, 13514, 13519, 13532, 13547, 13561, 
13575, 13589, 13603, 13617, 13630, 13645, 13658, 13679, 13694, 
13708, 13722, 13736, 13750, 13764, 13778, 13792, 13820, 13834, 
13846, 13862, 13882, 13896, 13915, 13925, 13939, 13953, 13967, 
13981, 13995, 14009, 14049, 14051, 14064, 14093, 14099, 14107, 
14121, 14149, 14156, 14163, 14177, 14191, 14205, 14233, 14254, 
14268, 14282, 14296, 14310, 14338, 14352, 14366, 14380, 14450, 
14474, 14492, 14506, 14520, 14534, 14548, 14562, 14575, 14590, 
14618, 14646, 14652, 14661, 14674, 14688, 14702, 14716, 14726, 
14744, 14758, 14793, 14807, 14821, 14834, 14849, 14863, 14877, 
14891, 14905, 14919, 14933, 14960, 14982, 14995, 15008, 15024, 
15038, 15065, 15078, 15093, 15108, 15112, 15121, 15135, 15168, 
15181, 15196, 15209, 15224, 15237, 15252, 15264, 15280, 15293, 
15307, 15308, 15322, 15343, 15353, 15371, 15384, 15399, 15427, 
15440, 15455, 15468, 15483, 15495, 15510, 15524, 15538, 15539, 
15568, 15580, 15595, 15608, 15623, 15635, 15636, 15651, 15666, 
15679, 15692, 15712, 15729, 15741, 15770, 15780, 15799, 15811, 
15826, 15833, 15853, 15911, 15924, 15940, 15961, 15996, 16024, 
16052, 16101, 16150, 16178, 16218, 16262, 16276, 16290, 16303, 
16318, 16331, 16346, 16360, 16374, 16388, 16401, 16417, 16442, 
16455, 16473, 16482, 16499, 16513, 16532, 16542, 16555, 16569, 
16585, 16612, 16624, 16638, 16653, 16667, 16682, 16697, 16706, 
16723, 16752, 16778, 16805, 16840, 16862, 16891, 16918, 16933, 
16976, 17030, 17044, 17120, 17143, 17178, 17219, 17233, 17261, 
17289, 17347, 17360, 17373, 17401, 17460, 17515, 17547, 17568, 
17579, 17583, 17602, 17626, 17653), class = "Date"), Year = c(1993, 
1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 
1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 
1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 
1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1997, 1997, 1997, 
1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1998, 1998, 
1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 
1998, 1998, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 
1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
2002, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 
2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 
2003, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 
2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 
2004, 2004, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2006, 2016, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 
2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 
2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 
2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 
2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 
2007, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 
2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 
2008, 2008, 2008, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 
2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 
2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 
2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018), Oxygen = c(4.11230769230769, 
NA, 5.98, 3.64576923076923, 5.76538461538462, 5.23153846153846, 
5.14807692307692, 4.26590909090909, 3.71666666666667, 4.35884615384615, 
3.25769230769231, 4.68653846153846, 5.01923076923077, 5.61923076923077, 
4.15576923076923, 4.55576923076923, 5.72884615384615, 7.22692307692308, 
2, 4.21923076923077, NA, 5.125, 4.74230769230769, 4.28846153846154, 
5.10384615384615, 6.06346153846154, 3.24230769230769, 6.07884615384615, 
5.89615384615385, 4.54807692307692, 5.32884615384615, 5.1, 5.48461538461538, 
6.70769230769231, 5.36538461538461, 5.22884615384615, 5.12083333333333, 
5.95, 5.55384615384615, 5.67153846153846, 5.53769230769231, 5.78307692307692, 
6.57307692307692, 6.49192307692308, 6.36153846153846, 6.136, 
7.30384615384615, 6.41153846153846, 6.6272, 6.41, 7.14782608695652, 
6.11307692307692, 6.20961538461538, 6.85277777777778, 6.82277777777778, 
6.82846153846154, 6.35384615384615, 5.15769230769231, 6.64, 6.69115384615385, 
6.39807692307692, 6.09230769230769, 6.97192307692308, 6.67384615384615, 
6.99961538461538, 6.60615384615385, 6.27692307692308, 6.82192307692308, 
7.45923076923077, 6.96307692307692, 7.11153846153846, 7.59384615384615, 
NA, 6.99692307692308, 6.98961538461538, 6.86192307692308, 6.80346153846154, 
7.08684615384615, 7.31692307692308, 6.23423076923077, NA, 4.195, 
5.16230769230769, 5.07423076923077, 6.57769230769231, 7.30692307692308, 
6.60884615384615, 5.39115384615385, 9.515, 8.25384615384615, 
7.65884615384615, 7.16461538461538, 8.12538461538461, 6.96153846153846, 
6.48038461538462, 6.09538461538462, 6.36884615384615, 5.1, NA, 
7.24961538461538, 6.36230769230769, 6.20615384615385, 6.31115384615385, 
6.06961538461538, 7.80846153846154, 6.26038461538462, 6.52769230769231, 
7.49557692307692, 7.47923076923077, 7.22692307692308, 6.57, 7.53615384615385, 
5.97192307692308, 7.65461538461538, NA, 5.41384615384615, 6.76384615384615, 
7.58173076923077, 7.426, 6.93307692307692, 8.06211538461539, 
7.43148148148148, 6.93307692307692, 6.865, 6.75076923076923, 
7.24076923076923, 7.54961538461538, 5.55653846153846, 8.41923076923077, 
6.75423076923077, 7.13653846153846, 7.00192307692308, 7.50576923076923, 
6.685, 7.29730769230769, 7.00730769230769, 7.85076923076923, 
6.46192307692308, 5.28038461538462, 5.23423076923077, 6.64884615384615, 
5.60769230769231, 7.17192307692308, 6.485, 6.74269230769231, 
6.27807692307692, 5.49653846153846, 7.06538461538462, 5.76846153846154, 
6.06846153846154, 7.58461538461538, 6.68, 6.00192307692308, 5.66307692307692, 
6.73307692307692, 6.79384615384615, 7.00423076923077, 6.12038461538462, 
4.40576923076923, 6.86269230769231, 6.21961538461538, 6.37346153846154, 
5.68423076923077, 6.27346153846154, 6.22846153846154, 4.76807692307692, 
5.01076923076923, 4.66423076923077, 6.43807692307692, 6.70423076923077, 
7.595, 5.61269230769231, 5.94615384615385, 5.53076923076923, 
6.31769230769231, 6.81576923076923, 6.66192307692308, 6.61269230769231, 
5.52307692307692, 5.91153846153846, 5.59230769230769, 5.16153846153846, 
6.18846153846154, 5.03846153846154, 5.41153846153846, 5.39230769230769, 
7.37846153846154, 5.44192307692308, 4.70384615384615, 5.45538461538461, 
5.09666666666667, 5.09115384615385, 4.48192307692308, 0.358333333333333, 
1.325, 2.17846153846154, 3.03384615384615, 5.36, 4.04730769230769, 
4.44538461538462, 4.42269230769231, 2.60666666666667, 3.28125, 
2.73961538461538, 7.02346153846154, 3.32038461538462, NA, 4.84423076923077, 
6.01153846153846, 4.70038461538462, 5.26269230769231, 5.26153846153846, 
4.67884615384615, 3.38038461538462, 0.709166666666667, 3.37, 
5.78076923076923, 0.565714285714286, 0.598333333333333, 1.7, 
4.23653846153846, 5.12038461538462, 4.41115384615385, 4.54192307692308, 
3.65615384615385, 4.30269230769231, 3.13807692307692, 1.41818181818182, 
0.94, 3.02115384615385, 1.87461538461538, 1.98, 4.58038461538462, 
4.73653846153846, 4.82846153846154, 4.115, 5.15307692307692, 
4.89076923076923, 5.09307692307692, 5.67653846153846, 4.90307692307692, 
4.99833333333333, 3.73461538461538, 3.48884615384615, 3.94615384615385, 
3.51038461538462, 3.27076923076923, 3.15192307692308, 2.62730769230769, 
4.04153846153846, 3.89115384615385, 3.59653846153846, NA, 5.32153846153846, 
6.68730769230769, 6.39269230769231, 6.50461538461538, 5.68576923076923, 
6.98807692307692, 5.40192307692308, 6.40538461538462, 6.57846153846154, 
5.25769230769231, 5.27461538461538, 6.19615384615385, 6.25384615384615, 
5.30192307692308, 5.32, 4.40583333333333, 5.85461538461538, 4.54269230769231, 
4.48, 5.92653846153846, 5.94538461538462, 5.95538461538462, 4.89730769230769, 
4.56384615384615, 5.88115384615385, 5.805, 4.58423076923077, 
NA, 6.07269230769231, 5.15923076923077, 5.97115384615385, 5.55346153846154, 
5.04230769230769, 5.15576923076923, 5.52615384615385, 6.54423076923077, 
5.66884615384615, 5.81692307692308, 5.93384615384615, 5.80846153846154, 
6.31692307692308, 5.81807692307692, 5.93038461538462, 5.95807692307692, 
6.32923076923077, 6.05384615384615, NA, 5.31923076923077, 6.98846153846154, 
5.71923076923077, 5.88461538461539, 8.3, 6.57692307692308, 6.29615384615385, 
8.08461538461538, 3.90384615384615, 7.64230769230769, 5.06153846153846, 
6.61923076923077, 6.42692307692308, 5.78846153846154, 7.24230769230769, 
6.61923076923077, 6.85, 7.31538461538462, 6.26538461538462, 7.35769230769231, 
6.04615384615385, 7.32692307692308, 6.30384615384615, 6.90846153846154, 
5.81538461538462, 7.39615384615385, 7.05, 6.15384615384615, 6.06538461538462, 
5.58076923076923, 6.29230769230769, 6.85, 6.72307692307692, 6.60769230769231, 
5.59230769230769, 4.65384615384615, 6.06153846153846, 6.13461538461539, 
6.36538461538461, 6.76538461538462, 6.22307692307692, 5.76153846153846, 
6.97692307692308, 5.85384615384615, 5.69230769230769, 6.85384615384615, 
6.83461538461538, 7.21923076923077, 7.65769230769231, 6.39230769230769, 
6.07692307692308, 5.96923076923077, 6.13846153846154, 6.15769230769231, 
6.6, 6.43076923076923, 6.47692307692308, 5.10769230769231, 5.65, 
2.02857142857143, 3.75, 1.38076923076923, 5.91538461538462, 5.36923076923077, 
5.26538461538462, 5.02307692307692, 4.64615384615385, 2.13076923076923, 
0.372222222222222, 4.62692307692308, NA, 4.65384615384615, 1.38461538461538, 
3.56153846153846, 4.88076923076923, 4.06153846153846, 5.43846153846154, 
4.42, 4.588, 4.78928571428571, 4.08076923076923, 4.74285714285714, 
5.93461538461538, 5.15, 5.23846153846154, 5.90384615384615, 3.96923076923077, 
5.71153846153846, 5.10384615384615, 5.81153846153846, 5.75, 5.82692307692308, 
6.10769230769231, 1.63846153846154, 5.37692307692308, 5.33461538461538, 
7.03846153846154, 5.59230769230769, 5.84230769230769, 6.024, 
3.81153846153846, 3.83846153846154, 5.7, 6.10769230769231, 5.58461538461538, 
5.06153846153846, 5.59230769230769, 5.59615384615385, 6.66538461538462, 
7.07307692307692, 7.85769230769231, 6.424, NA, 5.64814814814815, 
7.50769230769231, 5.83846153846154, 4.97692307692308, 2.83076923076923, 
1.25555555555556, 0.266666666666667, 4.87307692307692, 1.28888888888889, 
4.81923076923077, 4.82307692307692, 4.40384615384615, 5.36153846153846, 
3.67307692307692, 5.82692307692308, 1.31538461538462, 1.73846153846154, 
2.37307692307692, 2.74230769230769, 3.13461538461538, 1.73846153846154, 
2.36923076923077, NA, 2.16333333333333, 0.778571428571429, 1.40384615384615, 
2.93846153846154, 4.10961538461538, 1.37692307692308, 5.20769230769231, 
3.86269230769231, 4.02076923076923, 1.94291666666667, 2.708, 
4.35038461538462, 5.60307692307692, 3.755, 5.00961538461539, 
4.36307692307692, 3.245, 4.38769230769231, 3.26269230769231, 
NA, 5.01346153846154, 4.79653846153846, 4.46518518518519, 5.34461538461538, 
0.555384615384615, NA, 1.73192307692308, 2.23916666666667, 4.17307692307692, 
4.87461538461538, 5.50230769230769)), row.names = c(NA, -467L
), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "Date", drop = TRUE)
```

I want to average the monthly values for my data and create a new data frame with yearly means.

I tried to do this with this code:

```
YearlyAverage <- data %>%
group_by(Year) %>%
summarise(AverageOxygen = mean(as.numeric(as.character(Oxygen))))
```

However, I get this, which is filled with NAs when it shouldn't be:

```
structure(list(Year = c(1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 
2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 
2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018), AverageOxygen = c(NA, 
4.54928515928516, NA, 5.56936431623931, 6.55320160411247, 6.58626210826211, 
NA, NA, NA, 6.78180995475113, 6.14020979020979, 5.91730769230769, 
NA, 3.44465428801967, NA, NA, NA, 6.5642474916388, 6.32876923076923, 
NA, 5.37765610859728, NA, NA, 3.60876228632479, NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -26L))
```

What am I doing wrong here? And how can I fix this? Thank you kindly for your help.

Comment: (1) The data you provided has a column called `AverageOxygen` not `Oxygen`, are you sure that's right? (2) If there are NAs in the data (there are in the data you provided) you will get NAs back unless you use `na.rm = TRUE`, (3) Why are you coercing to character and numeric? Is `Oxygen` a factor? Because there are no factor variables in the data you provided.

Comment: @joran (1) Edited the column in question to be Oxygen. Sorry about that. (2) I'll check if `na.rm = TRUE` will fix the issue.
(3) It's just an old practice from older code that I left in. If it's wrong, I'll change that.

Comment: @joran Actually, if I use `na.rm = TRUE`, will it still take into that account that cell into the mean, or will it ignore that when calculating? I tried `na.rm = TRUE`, and it worked, there aren't any NAs. So now, I'm wondering if my first question holds.

Comment: `na.rm = TRUE` will drop all NA values before calculating the mean.

Comment: Hmm, I would want to include the NA into my mean calculation, the safest bet would probably convert it to 0, right?

Comment: Yes; in that case they aren't really NAs, then, are they? You know they should be zero.